# What does for mean in `if it were not for the protection`?

Tags: word-usage

I have read the sentence in "new concept english" book4 lesson2:

> Insects would make it impossible for us to live in the world;
> they would devour all our flocks and herds,
> if it were not for the protection we get from insect eating animals.

I can understand it, if the author write it as below:

> Insects would make it impossible for us to live in the world;
> they would devou all our flocks and herds,
> if without protection we get from insect eating animals.

"were not" is negative,the "for" in web dictionary:
[for meaning in the dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for)

> preposition
> 1.with the object or purpose of: to run for exercise.
> 2.intended to belong to, or be used in connection with: equipment for the army;a closet for dishes.
> 3.suiting the purposes or needs of: medicine for the aged.
> 4.in order to obtain, gain, or acquire: a suit for alimony;to work for wages.

what does "for" mean in "if it were not for the protection"?

Comment: _For_ doesn't have a separate meaning here; it's part of an idiom and the meaning comes from the combination, not from individual words.

Comment: "if without protection we get" might be understandable to you, but it is not grammatical and doesn't really make sense to a native English speaker.  *if* introduces a hypothetical.  But *without protection* suggests that we *don't* have protection, when the original sentence says that we *do*!  Also, since this is discussing a specific protection (the one that we get from insect-eating animals), it always has to be "*the* protection".

Comment: You had use backquotes and indenting,  This has the accidental effect of changing the font to a fixed font. It's useful for computer code, but not for normal writing. In English we can use inverted commas " or ' for quotes, and not `

Answer (score 6):

[If it were not for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if%20it%20were%20not%20for) is a standard idiom. The meaning is "if the  protection we get from insect-eating animals did not exist".